# Undefined columns selected error in R while reading multiple files

Tags: r

I have lot's of files in my directoy and I want to read all files and select the second columns of them and put those columns as rows of a matrix, but I face with strange error.

would anybody help me to figure out, what's going wrong with my code ?

Here is my effort:

```
#read all files in one directoy into R and select desired column
nm <- list.files(path="April/mRNA_expression/")
Gene_exp<-do.call(rbind, lapply(nm, function(x) read.table(file=x,header=TRUE, sep= ",")[, 2]))
save(Gene_exp, file="Path to folder")
```

The error I get is :

```
## Error in `[.data.frame`(read.table(file = x, header = TRUE, sep = ""),  :
## undefined columns selected*
```

To check that, really my files have 2 columns I did this :

```
b <- read.table("A.genes.normalized_results", sep="")
dim(b)
## [1] 20532     2
```

My text file Looks like this :

```
gene_id normalized_count
?|100130426 0.0000
?|100133144 10.6340
?|100134869 5.6790
?|10357 106.4628
?|10431 710.8902
?|136542    0.0000
?|155060    132.2883
?|26823 0.5098
?|280660    0.0000
?|317712    0.0000
?|340602    0.0000
?|388795    1.2745
?|390284    5.3527
?|391343    2.5489
?|391714    0.7647
?|404770    0.0000
?|441362    0.0000
```

Comment: Maybe `do.call(rbind, lapply(nm, function(x) tryCatch(read.table(file=x,header=TRUE, sep= ",")[, 3], error=function(e) stop(e, x))))` to find the bad file?

Answer (score 1):

The better solution would be to only import the second column when reading it. Use the `colClasses` argument to completely skip the first:

```
Gene_exp<-do.call(rbind, lapply(nm, function(x) read.delim(file=x,header=TRUE, colClasses=c('NULL', 'character'))))
```

I am assuming the second column is `character`. Change it to the appropriate class if you need to.

Comment: I got the similar error:   Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 2 elements

Comment: Your first row seems not to be formatted properly. Could you paste the first 5 lines of your text file?

Comment: Your file is not separated by commas, but TABs. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: I tried with sep= "", but still doesn't work, strange enough!

Comment: You should use `sep="\t"` or, use `read.delim` which is sets the separator to `"\t"` like I have shown in the answer.